# Transfer entropy calculation using PyPI package with a matrix data set

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, numpy-ndarray

I have a variance-covariance matrix and I am trying to compute transfer entropy using PyIF 0.1 package. In Jupyter notebook, I tried the following codes:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PyIF import te_compute as te
import numpy as np
```

```
X_1000 = pd.read_csv("1.csv")(6, 1).flatten()
Y_1000 = pd.read_csv("1.csv")(6, 1).flatten()
```

Here, the 1.csv date is a (6x6) matrix:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOUSC.png)

. I got the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-64837a8c877c> in <module>
----> 1 X_1000 = pd.read_csv("1.csv")(6, 1).flatten()
      2 Y_1000 = pd.read_csv("1.csv")(6, 1).flatten()

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Lastly, when I typed the command for calculating the transfer entropy using:

```
TE = te.te_compute(X_1000, Y_1000, k=1, embedding=1, safetyCheck=True, GPU=False)
```

I got following message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-92e8b850574f> in <module>
----> 1 TE = te.te_compute(X_1000, Y_1000, k=1, embedding=1, safetyCheck=True, GPU=False)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyIF/te_compute.py in te_compute(X, Y, k, embedding, safetyCheck, GPU)
     27     assert_true(k>=1, msg="K should be greater than or equal to 1")
     28     assert_true(embedding >= 1, msg='The embedding must be greater than or equal to 1')
---> 29     assert_true(type(X) == np.ndarray, msg='X should be a numpy array')
     30     assert_true(type(Y) == np.ndarray, msg='Y should be a numpy array')
     31     assert_true(len(X) == len(Y), msg='The length of X & Y are not equal')

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/unittest/case.py in assertTrue(self, expr, msg)
    763         if not expr:
    764             msg = self._formatMessage(msg, "%s is not true" % safe_repr(expr))
--> 765             raise self.failureException(msg)
    766 
    767     def _formatMessage(self, msg, standardMsg):

AssertionError: False is not true : X should be a numpy array
```

What could be the possible action for overcoming this issue? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: The parentheses after the code `X_1000 = pd.read_csv("1.csv")` raise the `TypeError`, because the function `pandas.read_csv` returns an instance of the class `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`, which is not callable. This can be confirmed by running the line as I modified it here, and then `print(type(X_1000))`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. It works. But what about the solution for X should be a numpy array?

Comment: The documentation of the called functions would be useful to decide how to proceed: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html and https://github.com/lcdm-uiuc/PyIF/blob/0466028754b19f066aaa5836a4ccaf0ce49aeb87/PyIF/te_compute.py#L10-L25. Introspection within IPython can also be useful: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#main-features-of-the-interactive-shell.